# Why can't I save anything on my mongodb instance on mac os?

Tags: macos, mongodb

I've installed mongodb on macos v10.10.5 using homebrew.  However I'm unable to save any data.

The /data/db folder shows up normally.  It has files in it that get updated.

However no data ever will save.  I have tested it using genghisapp and also running from my MEAN stack app which I run locally.  In genghisapp when I try to add a collection, it appears initially when I add it, but once I refresh the page the collection disappears.  Saving data from my mean stack app also seems to have no results.

I tried creating the /data/db folder as root, or as my regular user, didn't make a difference.

It is possible that I am actually saving the data but not seeing it?  Is there another easy way to browse/write to the database other than genghisapp?

Thanks

Comment: The command line? Any MongoDB browser?

Comment: I tried the command line, also didn't work

Comment: Without the code it's probably impossible to help.

Comment: There is no specific code issue.  I have tried running genghisapp and it never saves anything. I've also run several apps that work fine on my linux computer and another mac laptop of my coworker.  It must be a setup problem.